# DrawString wider on one PC

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+

I'm using graphic.DrawString to well... draw a string.

I specify the Font Family, Font Size, Font Style, Graphics Unit.

Everything works well for 50 computers but for just one, the font is "bolder".
The characters are the same height but for some reason the "pixel" are double the width.

Can this be fixed with code?
Can this be fixed using a windows setting?

Comment: Is the base font missing on that one PC (i.e. the version that is not bold)?

Comment: Users can specify various text DPI settings in control panel - are you sure that drawstring is actually drawing it incorrectly?

Comment: well.. I was finaly able to reproduce the problem by setting

graphic.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit

seems to be a problem with the default settings of the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it changing the "Use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts" from Clear Type to Standard.

It can also be changed in the code by modifying graphic.TextRenderingHint

Answer (score 1):

It can be fixed by making sure the same applicable font are installed on all machines and making sure the windows personalization settings are the same, but ultimately, your code should never assume that DrawString will always draw the text the same width on every machine.  Fonts are meant to be variable, so when you choose a font, the actual font used may be different on each computer.  If possible, you should code your application in a way to handle the text being varying widths.  You can get the width of the text before drawing it by calling Graphics.MeasureString, such as:

```
Dim textSize As SizeF = graphic.MeasureString("text to measure", Me.Font, Me.ClientRectangle.Width)
```